# Render multiple equations symbols side by side in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter, render, sympy, display, equation

Printing equations from sympy can be tricky in Jupyter. IPython.display has the display function, but it will only render one item per line.

Using print() you loose the latex formatting

I wanted to display multiple items in the same line but couldn't find anything to easily do this online. Hopefully this simple function will help others

Answer (score 0):

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
from sympy import Matrix, I, latex

def printmult(lst):
    output = ""
    for l in lst:
        if isinstance(l, str):
            output += f"{l}"
        else:
            output += f"${{{latex(l)}}}$ "

    display(Markdown(output))


Xm = Matrix([[0,1],[1,0]])
Ym = Matrix([[0,-I],[I,0]])

K1 = Matrix([[0],[1]])

res = Xm*Ym*K1
print("Each renders on a different line")
display (Xm, Ym, K1, " = ", res)

print("All render on the same line")
printmult([Xm, Ym, K1, " = ", res])
```

Output:

[image]

Edit: in response to @Oscar

Probably not the best example used above. The reason I needed the function above was to display one liners like below (nonsensical example)
Is there an earlier way to do this?

[image]

Comment: You can do `display(Eq(MatMul(Xm, Ym, K1), res))`